# What is the mutual incoherence of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

While working on an exercise, I stumbled upon the term *mutual incoherence of a matrix*. Upon googling, I didn't find much information outside of some of its properties, but nowhere any definitions. The only thing I found is the definition of a *mutual coherence of a matrix*.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_coherence_(linear_algebra)) gives the definition
$$
M = \max_{1 \leq i \neq j \leq m}|a_i^H a_j|
$$
where $a_1,\dots,a_m$ are the columns of a $d \times m$ matrix and $\|a_i\| = 1$ for all $i$.

Answer (score -1):

I am also not sure about the terminology, but it seems to be the same as the mutual coherence. In the following article (eq. 2) the mutual incoherence is defined similarly as the maximal inner product in absolute value between different columns.
[http://math.mit.edu/~liewang/OMP.pdf](http://math.mit.edu/%7Eliewang/OMP.pdf)